# relres in gmres MATLAB

Tags: matlab, iterative-method, gmres

I think the relres in MATLABis the form that relres = norm(M(b-A*x))/norm(M\b),when it smaller than tol then stop the iteration.
I want to know how to change relres to norm((b-A*x))/norm(b). Or use other code instead of the built-in one

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of that definition is that computing relres comes "for free" from the GMRES iteration. You could switch to the other definition without the preconditioner, but then you'd have to use more operations to compute it.

I don't think you can get anything significantly faster than trivially computing $b-Ax$ from scratch at every step. As far as I can read in the docs, Matlab's `gmres` does not have a callback to introduce a custom stopping criterion, so you'd have to modify its source code yourself (which is available --- type `edit gmres` to read it).